# Java Calendar and Time UTC to BST

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, java-8

I get a string in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm which represents a Date and Time in UTC.
Next step is to put this into a Calendar (with TimeZone UTC).

In addition need to also create a separate Calendar which has converted the UTC to "Europe/London" timeZone (GMT/BST).

After that I need to be able to detect if the "Europe/London" calendar has a DST (Day Light Savings Offset).

The code below will show you how far I have got and it runs ok on a UK based computer whose default System Timezone is GMT. However when I run it on a pc whose timezone is UTC it fails. It seems to not be able to tell me if there is an DST_offset (its always zero).

```
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 27);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    //This is required as Java Date JAN starts at 0.
    int MonthCon = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1;
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, MonthCon);
    Date d = cal.getTime();



    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssz");
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println("UTC:    " + f.format(d));
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
    System.out.println("BST:    " + f.format(d));

    //Creates a BST calendar of the same UTC time
    String dateStrBST = f.format(d);

    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssz");
    curFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
    Date dateObjBST = curFormater.parse(dateStrBST);


    System.out.println("BSTNewDate:    " + f.format(dateObjBST));


    Calendar calBST = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("BST"));
    calBST.setTime(dateObjBST);

    System.out.println("Current TimeZone is : " +  calBST.getTimeZone());

    int offset = calBST.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
    System.out.println("Day Light Savings: "+offset);
    System.out.println("Transition Day: "+isDSTTransitionDay(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))+"   Transition Type: "+DSTtransitionType(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
```

Unfortunately I need to be able to detect if any particular day is a transition day, that is to say a day that changes from DST on/off or off/on. Again this works on the local computer but not on the UTC timezone one.

```
 private static boolean isDSTTransitionDay(int year, int month, int day) throws ParseException
 {
         Calendar calStartofDay = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
         calStartofDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
         calStartofDay.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
         calStartofDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
         calStartofDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
         calStartofDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
         calStartofDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);            
         Date dStartofDay = calStartofDay.getTime();            

         SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssz");                        
         f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));            
         String dateStrUTCtoBST = f.format(dStartofDay);


         SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssz");
         curFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
         Date dateObjBST = curFormater.parse(dateStrUTCtoBST);
         Calendar calBST = Calendar.getInstance();
         calBST.setTime(dateObjBST);            

         int offsetStart = calBST.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);

         calBST.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);

         int offsetEnd = calBST.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
         //System.out.println("Start: "+offsetStart+" End: "+offsetEnd);




         if (offsetEnd == offsetStart) 
         {
             return false;
         }else
             {
                 //if(offsetStart<offsetEnd) {System.out.println("Transition to BST");}else{System.out.println("Transition to UTC/GMT");};
                 return true;
             }
 }
```

So on the UTC computer it fails miserably as it always puts Calendar.DST_OFFSET at zero.  I have clearly misunderstood something along the way so any help/clarity would be good.

I pretty much have to keep Calendars as the rest of the code uses it but I realise the Java8 has many more fancy ways to do things.

Comment: AFAIK, UTC doesn't ever have a DST.
GMT is not equal to UTC.

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london

Comment: "UTC computer it fails miserably as it always puts Calendar.DST_OFFSET at zero" its should always be an offset of zero by definition. What do you expect it to do?  BTW in French, UTC is defined at 1 in Paris, rather than London.

Comment: Aside, why are you subtracting one from month *after* setting all the values? In other words, you are first setting month incorrectly, then correcting. Better set it correctly from the start: `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0)` or even better `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
Calendar calBST = Calendar.getInstance();
```

That sets calBST to the computer's timezone (on the UTC computer, it will be UTC).

`calBST.setTime(dateObjBST);` sets the time, not the timezone.

Try using `getInstance(TimeZone zone)` there also.

---

In any case, I would replace your code like this:

```
Calendar calStartofDay = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
calStartofDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
calStartofDay.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
calStartofDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 21);
calStartofDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
calStartofDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calStartofDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);            

Calendar calBST = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
calBST.setTimeInMillis(calStartofDay.getTimeInMillis());
// use this to check the time
System.out.printf("%tc%n", calBST);
```

Also, from the Calendar docs, be careful about this:

> set(f, value) changes calendar field f to value. In addition, it sets
>   an internal member variable to indicate that calendar field f has been
>   changed. Although calendar field f is changed immediately, the
>   calendar's time value in milliseconds is not recomputed until the next
>   call to get(), getTime(), getTimeInMillis(), add(), or roll() is made.
>   Thus, multiple calls to set() do not trigger multiple, unnecessary
>   computations. As a result of changing a calendar field using set(),
>   other calendar fields may also change, depending on the calendar
>   field, the calendar field value, and the calendar system. In addition,
>   get(f) will not necessarily return value set by the call to the set
>   method after the calendar fields have been recomputed. The specifics
>   are determined by the concrete calendar class.

Comment: It tried: Calendar calBST = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London")); nbut results in a  java.lang.NullPointerException. If i use "UTC" its fine ?

Comment: on my PC, I didn't get a NullPointerException, and I tried with different cities...

From the "getTimeZone" docs: "Return: the specified TimeZone, or the GMT zone if the given ID cannot be understood."

So it's quite strange you got a NPE

Comment: I am running this on AWS Lambda ... if that makes any difference.

Comment: Any chance you can go on chat

Comment: FYI, the old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 2):

Please allow me to be honest, I tried to read your code and didn’t really understand your way of trying to obtain what you want. If you can use Java 8, I recommend switching to using the Java 8 date and time classes. With these your job isn’t very complicated. For the demonstration I have chosen last October 30, the date when Britain (and EU) changed back from summer time (daylight saving time) to standard time.

```
String originalDate = "2016-10-30 23:35";
LocalDateTime localTime = LocalDateTime.parse(originalDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
ZonedDateTime utcTime = localTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime bstTime = utcTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
// the summer time offset is how many milliseconds?
long dstOffset = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(utcTime.toLocalDateTime(), bstTime.toLocalDateTime());
System.out.println(dstOffset); // prints 0

// try the same at start of day (midnight)
utcTime = utcTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
bstTime = utcTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
dstOffset = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(utcTime.toLocalDateTime(), bstTime.toLocalDateTime());
System.out.println(dstOffset); // prints 3600000

// and next midnight
utcTime = utcTime.plusDays(1);
bstTime = utcTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
dstOffset = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(utcTime.toLocalDateTime(), bstTime.toLocalDateTime());
System.out.println(dstOffset); // prints 0
```